# Add property to each object of specific structure JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object :

```
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};
```

How can I add to each object in groups `id` with the same value as in `name prop` to get this:

```
   const obj2 = {
      app: {
        groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values', id: 'name' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1', id: 'name1' }]
      },
      app2: {
        groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values', id: 'name2' }, { name: 'name7', values: 'values4', id: 'name7' }]
      },
      app3: {
        groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5', id: 'name5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4', id: 'name4' }]
      }
    };
```

Comment: With a loop, hence... What have you tried so far? Any errors you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mutable version:** If you can modify your input object, use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) twice:

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  obj[key].groups.forEach(x => x.id = x.name);
});

console.log(obj);
```

**Immutable version:** If you don't want to modify your input object, use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and the spread operator to copy properties from the inner objects:

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc[key] = { groups: val.groups.map(x => ({ ...x, id: x.name })) };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

In both cases, you'll need to iterate over the keys using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or directly over the entries with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `for..in` and `forEach`

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

for (let item in obj) {
 obj[item].groups.forEach(o => o.id = o.name)
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your object and then loop through the array in your inner object:

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

for (app in obj) {
  obj[app].groups.forEach(innerObj => {
    innerObj.id = innerObj.name;
  });
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `Object.keys` and use `map` like so:

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

function addIdProp(object) {
  let result = object;
  Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
    result[key].groups = result[key].groups.map(({ name, values }) => { return { name, values, id: name}});
  });
  return result;
}

const obj2 = addIdProp(obj);

console.log(obj2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

function addIdProp(object) {
  var result = object;
  Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
    result[key].groups = result[key].groups.map(function({ name, values }) { return { name: name, values: values, id: name}});
  });
  return result;
}

var obj2 = addIdProp(obj);

console.log(obj2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about with this?

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

for (let k in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    obj[k].groups = obj[k].groups.map((g) => {
     return { ...g, id: g.name}
    })
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the object properties and add their `group` array a id prop assigning the relevant `name` with two nested `forEach`es as follows:

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{
      name: 'name',
      values: 'values'
    }, {
      name: 'name1',
      values: 'values1'
    }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{
      name: 'name2',
      values: 'values'
    }, {
      name: 'name2',
      values: 'values4'
    }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{
      name: 'name5',
      values: 'values5'
    }, {
      name: 'name4',
      values: 'values4'
    }]
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => obj[e].groups.forEach(el => el.id = el.name));

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Note that it does this implementation does not create a new object, instead modifies the initial one. Your use case may welcome or discourage it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const obj = {app: {groups: [{name: 'name',values: 'values'}, {name: 'name1',values: 'values1'}]},app2: {groups: [{name: 'name2',values: 'values'}, {name: 'name2',values: 'values4'}]},app3: {groups: [{name: 'name5',values: 'values5'}, {name: 'name4',values: 'values4'}]}};
const obj2 = Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({
  [k]: {
    groups: obj[k].groups.map(o => {
      o.id = o.name;
      return o;
    })
  }
}));

console.log(obj2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that is purely function, immutable, and independent of scope/closure would be to reduce the `[Object.entries()][1]` of the `obj` into a new `obj2` result like so:

```js
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1' }]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

/* Reduce entries into a new object */
const obj2 = Object.entries(obj).reduce((newObject, [key, value]) => {
  
  /* For each value of new object array of, map group items to include id : name property */
  newObject[ key ] = { groups : value.groups.map(item => ({ ...item, id : item.name })) }
  
  return newObject

}, {})

console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the object first and then map inside the groups array like that:

```
const obj = {
  app: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name1', values: 'values1'}]
  },
  app2: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name2', values: 'values' }, { name: 'name2', values: 'values4' }]
  },
  app3: {
    groups: [{ name: 'name5', values: 'values5' }, { name: 'name4', values: 'values4' }]
  }
};

var newObj = {...obj};
for(var key in newObj){
    newObj[key] = newObj[key].groups.map(item => ({...item, id: item.name}));
}

console.log(newObj); // here is your new object with id's
```